# User input break at no input or non-numeric input

Tags: java, loops, input, arraylist

The program is supposed to ask the user for a number, and loops until the input is not a number (repeats if there is a number input).
My code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MataVarden
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        ArrayList<Integer> Values = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        System.out.print("Input a number: ");
        Values.add(sc.nextInt()); 

        Collections.sort(Values);
        System.out.println("Values sorted: " + Values);
    }
}
```

What do you need to do in order to break an input if a non-number is entered?

Comment: You might want to think about what sc.nextInt() will do when the user doesn't enter a number (<enter> or "ABC"). You might also want to look at the Scanner API, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop for these case.

```
System.out.println("Input a number");
String line = "";
while (sc.hasNextLine() && !(line = sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
    try {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(line);
        values.add(val);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Input a number");
}
```

Ok now, here's an explanation of what's happening there: -

- `sc.hasNextLine()` checks whether there is an input to read or not. If yes then proceed to the next test
- `!(line = sc.nextLine()).equals("")` checks whether the next input is an `empty string` or not. If it's an empty string, the condition fails, and loop ends.
- Since we are reading the input using `nextLine()` method, we would have to parse it to integer using `Integer.parseInt(line);`
- We need to enclose it in a `try-catch` block to handle input like `"abc"`, which will not be parsed to an integer, and will throw an exception, in which case, we break out of the `while loop` from the `catch block`.
- Note that I haven't used `sc.nextInt()` because it does not read the newline token from the input. So, there would not be any way to know when to terminate the loop.

---

As a side note, you should always follow Coding conventions in your code. Your variable name should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: This will not work as specified as it will not break out of the loop when a non-number or null has been entered.

Comment: @Pescis. Well, it will work for non-number. For enter, yes, I'll edit the code.

Comment: Although this is OK, I think that if a question is asked on a coursework it is more responsible to give an idea of what is going on and how to tackle the question rather than just giving an answer like this.

Comment: @NutterzUK.. I would like you to remove your downvote, of course if you have done.

Comment: @NutterzUK.. Understand that it takes some time to write some explanation. It's not that I have all the answer stored somewhere and just copy-paste from there. And I myself don't believe on just give away code like answer.

Comment: @RohitJain Thank you very much! And thanks alot for the explanation too! This works like a charm, now im just gonna study it more so i fully understand it. Thanks alot!

Comment: @user1864418.. You're welcome. Remember, whenever you want to repeat a task, you definitely need a loop. Mostly while loop.